# c++ / cll - spinner text

Tags: c++-cli, spinner

I have text like

> I {love|enjoy|like{| reading| posting on}} {stack|stackover}. {:D |:)
>   |^^ |}{They{| are {forums|boards} that}|The {boards|forums|bbs}}
>   provide {free|awesome|infomrative|new} {guides|ideas|tutorials|posts}
>   (and {tools|downloads|books}!)

in String^ Szablon
and want to generate text from that.

I write a code:

```
 while ((str = din->ReadLine()) != nullptr)  //read from the file
  {

        int rndInt;
        tekst=Szablon;

        int i=0;

        while (i<5){

        Regex^ spin = gcnew Regex("{[^{}]*}");
        String^ delimStr = "|";
        Match^ m = spin->Match(tekst);

        if ( m->Success ) 
             {
                array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
                array<String^>^ words;  
                words = m->Value->Split( delimiter );
                words[0] = words[0]->Replace("{","");
                words[words->Length-1] = words[words->Length-1]->Replace("}","");
                Random^ r = gcnew Random();

                int x=r->Next(0,words->Length);
                String^ aktualny=words[x];
                tekst = tekst->Replace(m->Value,aktualny);

            }       
            else {i=8;}

        }


        MessageBox::Show(tekst);}
```

and it's working, but it generate me all the time the same results

Comment: We'd expect you to use "str" somewhere in your code.  Perhaps you'd be ahead by deleting Szablon, whatever it might mean.  And use tekst = str;

Comment: this is only part of code and "str" is not important here. If i do other loop "text" it gives me all the time the same results

Comment: Hmm, 'kay.  You need to move the Random object out of this code, it needs to be stored as a field in the class in which this code appears.  The way you are using it now, it constantly gets re-initialized with the same seed (based on the current time), so is highly likely to constantly produces the same random number.  Time changes only with 15.6 msec intervals.  Create it just once, make it *static* if necessary.

Comment: Do you have of example of that class ?